# When can I use "to be"?

Tags: grammar

it is not clear to me when do I have to use "to be"

In internet I can't find how because all the pages I see talk about "verb to be" and I read the classic "I am, you are, he is", but I want to know when I must use "to be", literally "to be".

For example

> They are supposed to be good parents"

Comment: You just *did* use it in your example sentence. Do you doubt that it was used correctly?

Comment: "To be" is most easily understood as a prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 2):

"To be" is the "infinitive" form of that verb. It is also called the "to-infinitive." That is the form of the verb we use when we want to identify a particular verb (the action-word itself) for any purpose, so when you look up "to be", you find all kinds of rules about *all* forms of it ... "I am, he is, they would have been" ...etc., blah blah.

If you want to know about using "to be", in exactly that form, you need to look up how to use the "infinitive" or the "to-infinitive" of the verb.

Here are two common situations where you would use "to be":

> With another verb -
>
> "I **want to be** a professional athlete."
>
> "We were **told to be** quiet."
>
> or your example, "They are **supposed to be** good parents."
>
> ---
>
> When you want it to function as a noun (talking about the abstract concept of "being") -
>
> "**To be** in prison for a year is horrible."
>
> "**To be** happy all the time is impossible."
>
> "**To be** or not **to be**, that is the question."

"To be" is used in many different ways and  situations, and there are lots of details and rules about it, so it would be impossible to make a simple list of them all.

But you can find lots of articles about how to use the infinitive form of verbs.

For example: this "[LearnEnglish](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/infinitives)" article from the British Council. The rules listed there can be applied to specific verbs including "**to be**".

Answer (score 0):

Infinitive is 'to be'.

It is tough *to be* the winner.

Present participle or gerund is being.

*Being* the winner is great.

Past participle is been.

I have *been* a winner.

The use of an infinitive may confuse you since it is creates a generic term.
It is good *to be* King. or *To be* a runner is a healthy pastime.

Specific term would be, I *am* the King and no one else is.